# Existe uma lista com todas as propriedades que precisam de prefixos?

Tags: css, css3

Estou com uma dúvida sobre CSS:

Para rodar em diferentes navegadores preciso usar o prefixo antes da propriedade, por exemplo: `-webkit-boder-left-rarius: 3px;`.

Mas quais CSS *styles* como `border`, `margin`, `transition` e por ai vai devo usar os prefixos? Tem alguma lista?

Comment: Mixins. Tem no Css-Tricks.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/useful-css3-less-mixins/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os prefixos servem para implementar alguns itens que não são compatíveis com outros navegadores, mas existe dentro de um navegador especifico.

Mas boa parte dos elementos CSS não precisam de prefixos e alguns que precisavam já não precisam mais.

Ex. `border-radius`ele está bem estável em todos os navegadores diferente do `backdrop-filter` que só existe no webkit do Safari para iOS 9 e precisa de um `-webkit-backdrop-filter`

**Como descobrir se precisa usar o prefixo ou não?**

Você pode consultar o [caniuse](http://caniuse.com) ele é bem fácil de usar, basta colocar o elemento que você quer usar e ver quais navegadores são compatíveis. Ele tem um ícone indicando quando a propriedade precisa do prefixo.

Apesar dessa abordagem ser mais trabalhosa do que usar um gerador, se você está aprendendo é o melhor caminho para ir conhecendo a evolução do CSS 3.

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro que você use um software para Build tal como o **Gulp**.

Neste caso você pode usar um *plugin* que vai acertar automaticamente os prefixos no seu CSS.

Exemplo de Plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer

Comment: Sabe me dizer se existe algum similar para o grunt? Utilizo o grunt para a compilação com meu código feito em sass utilizando compass também. Normalmente eu utilizo o compass para fazer a definição do prefixo. Mas se tiver um fluxo mais automatizado direto na compilação, seria melhor.

Comment: Nunca usei, mas você pode testar esse: https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-postcss